# Insert div or custom-directive in contenteditable div at cursor position in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, contenteditable

I have to insert a custom directive in my contenteditable div.

```
   /*Editor Div*/
      <div id="edBody"  contenteditable="true"></div>
   /*Insert one custom directive*/
   <a ng-click="insertType('fibtext')">Add Directive</a>
```

I tried this:

```
  <input type="button" value="Insert" ng-click="addHtmlAtCaret('<dc-tags></dc-tags>')">
   /* Directive */
    asignmentApp.directive('dcTags', function() {
       return {
          restrict: 'E',
          template: 'new <b> Value </b>'
       };
    });
```

Please help me.  Fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/k2SUJ/1/

Here's a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k2SUJ/1/) which i tried.

Comment: is there a function definition for `addHtmlAtCaret` ?

Comment: @SnareHanger , i edited my question with fiddle link, what i tried is there. Kindly please check and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Angular to be aware of your added element and do its magic, you need to **[`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)** the element and link it to a scope.

So you'll need a controller with a scope. You also need to replace the `onclick` handlers with **[`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)** and also **[`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)** the element:

In HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="..." ng-click="addHtmlAtCaret(...)">
```

In JS:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($compile, $scope) {
    $scope.addHtmlAtCaret = function (html) {
        document.getElementById('test').focus();
        ...
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.innerHTML = html;
        $compile(el)($scope);
        ...
    };
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/C5R8M/)**.

Comment: this works fine. But, in crome when no pre-focus or clicked in between 'test' div, it insert new html at start position of div. I want to insert rather at end position of div. Would you please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DhananjayC: Here is an implementation that works in Chrome and Firefox. I didn't test it in other browsers (especially IE - I don't come with built-in support for IE). I have taken care of the non-IE9 stuff (you need to add support for IE9 or less). The idea is that you check the range before you focus the element. Then you compare it to the range after you focus the element. If they don't look the same, then the element was not focused and you append the new content to the end.

Comment: here is [Updated Link](http://jsfiddle.net/C5R8M/7/). And it works as expected in Chrome but not in firefox.

Answer (score -1):

Before Doing the paste It will be good to save the cursor and Restore it. In the case of button only above will work. but if you use Popover or Dialog on button and after Closing the dialog the Content Editable Div Focus will go at first in AngularJS App. So Before doing Above please do this too.
Consider This is your Content Editable Div as i show below.
on ng-click and ng-keyup i just save the current Cursor of the editable DIV and when user open a dialog ,or popup or perform any action and call the function addHtmlAtCaret(html), just resotred the cursor to the last inputed position and proceed the same way as explained by the user gkalpak above.

```js
var saveSelection, restoreSelection;
$scope.commentKeyInput = function(keyEvent,id) {  // (keyEvent.target).innerHTML='';
       if (keyEvent.which === 13){
         //alert('I am an alert');
       }
       else{
       var divID='comment'+id;        
      savedSelection = saveSelection(document.getElementById(divID));
//      savedSelection.start++;
//      console.log(savedSelection.start);
       }
     }         
      $scope.commentBoxClicked=function(event,id){  
       try{
         var divID='comment'+id;        
      savedSelection = saveSelection(document.getElementById(divID));  
//      console.log(savedSelection.start);
       }
       catch(e){
        alert(e);
       }  
      } 
      
      if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
         saveSelection = function(containerEl) {
             var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
             var preSelectionRange = range.cloneRange();
             preSelectionRange.selectNodeContents(containerEl);
             preSelectionRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
             var start = preSelectionRange.toString().length;

             readCounter++;              
             return {
                 start: start,
                 end: start + range.toString().length
             }
         };

         restoreSelection = function(containerEl, savedSel) {
             var charIndex = 0, range = document.createRange();
             range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
             range.collapse(true);
             var nodeStack = [containerEl], node, foundStart = false, stop = false;
//               console.log('Read Called '+readCounter+ " Node Type ="+node.nodeType);
//               readCounter++;              
             while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
                 if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                     var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
                     if (!foundStart && savedSel.start >= charIndex && savedSel.start <= nextCharIndex) {
                         range.setStart(node, savedSel.start - charIndex);
                         foundStart = true;
                     }
                     if (foundStart && savedSel.end >= charIndex && savedSel.end <= nextCharIndex) {
                         range.setEnd(node, savedSel.end - charIndex);
                         stop = true;
                     }
                     charIndex = nextCharIndex;
                 } else {
                     var i = node.childNodes.length;
                     while (i--) {
                         nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
                     }
                 }
             }

             var sel = window.getSelection();
             sel.removeAllRanges();
             sel.addRange(range);
         }
     } else if (document.selection && document.body.createTextRange) {
         saveSelection = function(containerEl) {
             var selectedTextRange = document.selection.createRange();
             var preSelectionTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
             preSelectionTextRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
             preSelectionTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", selectedTextRange);
             var start = preSelectionTextRange.text.length;

             return {
                 start: start,
                 end: start + selectedTextRange.text.length
             }
         };

         restoreSelection = function(containerEl, savedSel) {
             var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
             textRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
             textRange.collapse(true);
             textRange.moveEnd("character", savedSel.end);
             textRange.moveStart("character", savedSel.start);
             textRange.select();
         };
     } 
      
    $scope.addHtmlAtCaret = function (html) {
                if (savedSelection) {
                   restoreSelection(document.getElementById('comment0'), savedSelection);
                }          //document.getElementById('comment0').focus();
        var sel, range;
        if (window.getSelection) {
            // IE9 and non-IE
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
                range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                range.deleteContents();
    
                // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
                // non-standard and not supported in all browsers (IE9, for one)
                var el = document.createElement("div");
                el.innerHTML = html;
                $compile(el)($scope);
                var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
                while ( (node = el.firstChild) ) {
                    lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
                }
                range.insertNode(frag);
                
                // Preserve the selection
                if (lastNode) {
                    range = range.cloneRange();
                    range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                    range.collapse(true);
                    sel.removeAllRanges();
                    sel.addRange(range);
                }
            }
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
            // IE < 9
            document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
        }
    }
```

```html
<div contenteditable   ng-model="commentform.comment name="comment0" id="comment0"  placeholder="Write a comment..." ng-keyup="commentKeyInput($event,0)" ng-click="commentBoxClicked($event,0)" ></div>
```